# How to properly add iOS framework with location and create plugin from it in Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, location, cordova-plugins

I am writing Cordova plugin which wrap iOS framework which use location in background.
I have added necessary permissions and I have wrapped iOS framework successfully, but the location did not updates to me while I am moving. I got message from Cordova, please take a look at image.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean you don't receive updates in the webview or you don't receive updates at all? Because on iOS, the webview is completely paused and JS does not execute when the app is in the background, therefore you cannot respond to GPS events to the webview while in the background.

Comment: I did not receive any updates. And it starts to work when I move code for enabling location manager to app delegate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It start receiving updates when I moved the code which enables location manager into AppDelegate class. If that code is at some other class, the prompt window for location permission will appear but the monitoring of location changes will not work.
I am not totally sure why is that, but it works now :D